# Using a join with SQL function in view

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join, sql-view

This may be a very basic question for some of you, but please be patient with this newbie learning SQL server.

I need to create a view in which I am trying to join multiple columns from two tables. Only issue is, one of the columns has values that has extra characters, which need to be removed, by using the RIGHT function, or SUBSTRING, for it to be able to match the corresponding column in the other table.

Here is what I have written, but I need help on what I am doing wrong with the SerialNo column:

```
SELECT a.ID, 
       a.SerialNo, 
       a.Price, 
       a.ItemName, 
       b.ID, b.SNumber, 
       b.ItemDesc
FROM Table1 a LEFT JOIN
Table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID AND
            a.Price = b.Price AND
            a.SerialNo = (SELECT RIGHT(b.SNumber, 6) AS b.SNumber from Table2)
```

Comment: RIGHT(b.SNumber, 6) add this alone in join query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a subquery to handle the second join condition, just call `RIGHT` directly:

```
SELECT a.ID, a.SerialNo, a.Price, a.ItemName, b.ID, b.SNumber, b.ItemDesc
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b
ON a.ID = b.ID AND
   a.Price = b.Price AND
   a.SerialNo = RIGHT(b.SNumber, 6);
```

As a side note, if you think you would need to perform this query often, then you might want to consider adding a new column in `Table2` for this join, which is the first six characters of `SNumber`.  The reason for this is that joins can be very costly when the conditions involve functions.  And also, indexes generally cannot be used in this case either.

Comment: thank you! Your quick response was very useful in helping me complete something.